# Auto select is not working in augularjs for select2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<ui-select ng-model="type.selected" theme="bootstrap" >
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Test Type">{{$select.selected.type_name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="type in types | filter: $select.search" >
    <div ng-bind-html="type.type_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Angularjs code to auto select list is

```
var selected_type_index = $scope.types.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(data.test.type_id);
$scope.types = angular.extend($scope.types, {type:{selected:$scope.types[selected_type_index]}});
```

Object is right in `$scope.types[selected_type_index]` but auto select is not working

What I am doing wrong, Or please suggest if any other good solution to auto select.

thanks in advance

Comment: could you create a plunker, http://plnkr.co

Comment: i have posted the a codepen below, see if it helps else udpate your code there and let me know whats the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to just update the model  `type.selected` of your `ui-select` with new value available in the list.
you can update the model in two ways

1. directive level.   `<input type="button" ng-click="superhero.selected='Thor'" value = "My Hero !!!">`
2. Controller level. `$scope.superhero.selected = "Thor"`

[Working example @ Codepen](http://codepen.io/dreamweiver/pen/VaQWML)

you may need to update this below model in your code snippet with appropriate new value.

```
type.selected = "new value";
```